# lots of netstat entries

Tags: virus, netstat

I have a lot of nestat entries in my cmd window of windows7 and I have a bad feeling about this.
I just logged in and I am googling here on this page.
Do I have a security issue ? Virus ?

```
  TCP    192.168.1.55:49198     HPCF7CC0:8080          HERGESTELLT
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52007     zrh04s06-in-f24:https  WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52020     zrh04s05-in-f16:https  WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52058     static:http            WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52059     zrh04s06-in-f15:https  WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52060     zrh04s08-in-f0:https   WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52062     zrh04s05-in-f1:https   WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52063     static:http            WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52064     zrh04s06-in-f24:http   WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52067     static:http            WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52069     static:http            WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52070     li348-213:http         WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52072     zrh04s06-in-f14:http   WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52073     zrh04s05-in-f13:http   WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52078     zrh04s06-in-f2:http    WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52079     185.31.17.185:http     WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52080     95.100.63.139:http     WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52082     li348-213:http         WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52083     zrh04s05-in-f15:http   WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52084     zrh04s08-in-f25:http   WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52085     zrh04s08-in-f25:http   WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52086     zrh04s05-in-f13:http   WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52087     zrh04s05-in-f13:http   WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52090     li348-213:http         WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52091     li348-213:http         WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52092     zrh04s08-in-f25:http   WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52096     li348-213:http         WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52097     zrh04s05-in-f15:http   WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52099     193.247.166.41:http    WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52100     zrh04s05-in-f15:http   WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52102     li348-213:http         WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52103     li348-213:http         WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52104     zrh04s08-in-f0:http    WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52105     li348-213:http         WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52106     edge-star-shv-09-fra2:http  WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52107     edge-star-shv-09-fra2:http  WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52109     edge-star-shv-09-fra2:http  WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52110     edge-star-shv-09-fra2:http  WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52112     li348-213:http         WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52113     185.31.17.196:http     WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52115     a23-57-107-27:http     WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52116     a23-57-107-27:http     WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52118     a23-54-17-224:http     WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52119     a23-54-17-224:http     WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52120     li348-213:http         WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52122     193.247.166.41:http    WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52123     193.247.166.48:http    WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52124     193.247.166.48:http    WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52125     193.247.166.48:http    WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52126     193.247.166.48:http    WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52127     193.247.166.48:http    WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52128     193.247.166.48:http    WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52129     193.247.166.41:http    WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52130     zrh04s05-in-f16:http   WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52131     fa-in-f84:https        WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52132     zrh04s05-in-f4:http    WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52133     li348-213:http         WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52134     li348-213:http         WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52135     li348-213:http         WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52136     li348-213:http         WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52139     a23-54-107-27:http     WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52140     zrh04s05-in-f15:https  WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52141     zrh04s08-in-f25:https  WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52142     zrh04s05-in-f10:https  WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52143     a23-54-17-224:http     WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52144     a23-54-17-224:http     WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52148     li348-213:http         WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52149     li348-213:http         WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52150     li348-213:http         WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52151     li348-213:http         WARTEND
  TCP    192.168.1.55:52157     li348-213:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52164     li348-213:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52165     li348-213:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52168     li348-213:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52169     li348-213:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52172     li348-213:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52173     li348-213:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52174     zrh04s05-in-f15:https  WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52176     li348-213:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52178     li348-213:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52179     li348-213:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52180     li348-213:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52181     li348-213:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52182     li348-213:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52183     li348-213:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52184     li348-213:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52185     li348-213:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52186     li348-213:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52201     fa-in-f95:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52202     fa-in-f95:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52207     ec2-184-73-236-147:http  WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52208     fa-in-f95:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52209     fa-in-f95:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52210     76.72.162.203:http     WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52212     185.31.17.196:http     WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52215     beckandcall:http       WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52216     fa-in-f95:https        WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52219     zrh04s05-in-f15:https  WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52221     193.247.166.43:http    WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52223     76.72.162.203:http     WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52225     76.72.162.203:http     WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52227     185.29.133.223:http    WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52228     185.31.17.134:http     WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52231     fa-in-f95:https        WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52232     fa-in-f95:https        WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52233     zrh04s05-in-f27:http   WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52234     zrh04s05-in-f27:http   WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52236     fa-in-f95:https        WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52237     zrh04s08-in-f28:http   WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52238     zrh04s08-in-f28:http   WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52239     zrh04s05-in-f12:https  WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52242     zrh04s06-in-f3:http    WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52245     95.101.40.214:http     WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52246     zrh04s05-in-f1:http    WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52247     zrh04s05-in-f1:http    WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52248     ec2-184-73-184-214:http  WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52249     ec2-23-22-67-55:http   WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52250     193.247.166.41:http    WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52252     193.247.166.72:http    WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52253     ec2-23-22-67-55:http   WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52254     ec2-184-73-184-214:http  WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52257     185.31.17.196:http     WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52259     185.31.17.196:http     WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52260     par10s10-in-f15:https  WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52261     ec2-176-34-120-59:http  WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52262     ec2-176-34-120-59:http  WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52265     67:http                WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52267     193.247.166.41:http    WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52268     xx-fbcdn-shv-05-fra2:http  WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52269     xx-fbcdn-shv-05-fra2:http  WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52270     xx-fbcdn-shv-06-fra2:http  WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52271     ec2-184-73-16-50:http  WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52272     212.243.210.11:http    WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52274     ec2-184-73-16-50:http  WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52275     193.247.166.43:http    WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52276     193.247.166.43:http    WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52277     193.247.166.43:http    WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52278     193.247.166.43:http    WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52281     91.225.248.80:http     WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52282     91.225.248.80:http     WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52283     193.247.166.41:http    WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52284     193.247.166.41:http    WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52285     68.232.35.139:http     WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52286     68.232.35.139:http     WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52290     li348-213:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52294     li348-213:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52295     185.31.17.196:http     WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52296     li348-213:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52297     li348-213:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52299     li348-213:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52300     li348-213:http         WARTEND
 TCP    192.168.1.55:52301     193.247.166.41:http    WARTEND
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really anything to be concerned about. Your computer has established a numerous amount of HTTP connections to some servers via TCP, which is completely normal, even when your browser isn't open. Most of them are real websites that you are currently connected to.

For example, `zrh04s06-in-f2` belongs to `1e100.net` which is owned by Google (1e100 = 1 googol, get it?). If you're connected to anything Google-related, chances are that you've made a connection to somewhere in `1e100`.